# MYSQL On Duplicate Key Update only if there is particular value in the record

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a MySQL table with 4 columns:

```
    personId(int)
    dateX(date)
    ratio(decimal 11,2)
    closed(boolean, e.g. tintyint(1)).
```

personId and dateX is the primary key.
3 first columns are the ones that are really in use, the fourth one just serves as an indicator, that this record should not be modified anymore, as this value has been used for some calculations, hence it should stay static. I was using this query:

```
INSERT INTO ratioTable(personId,dateX,ratio) VALUES (:personId,:dateX,:ratio) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE personId=:personId,dateX=:dateX, ratio=:ratio;
```

And it worked just fine. However, it doesn't take any "closed" records into consideration. I tried to do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO ratioTable(personId,dateX,ratio) VALUES (:personId,:dateX,:ratio) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE personId=:personId,dateX=:dateX, ratio=IF(closed=1,ratio,:ratio);
```

but it doesn't work. If there is ANY record with closed=1 it doesn't update any of them. 
I've also tried the other type of query that I've found on the web:

```
INSERT INTO ratioTable(personId,dateX,ratio) VALUES (:personId,:dateX,:ratio) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE personId=:personId,dateX=:dateX, ratio=:ratio WHERE closed!=1;
```

but this gives me a MySQL error.

Could you please point me out in the right direction, what do I do wrong? I need to perform query that inserts a record, but if there is already a record with the same primary key then it should check if the "closed" parameter != 1 and update this record. I don't want to run SELECT query beforehand, and I believe that there should be a way to perform it with just one MySQL query. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic, I think the primary key should be either `(personId, closed)` or `(personId, dateX, closed)`.  I can't quite tell from your description.  Do you want:

1. Up to two records for each person, one open and one closed?
2. Up to two records for each person on each day, one open and one closed?
3. Multiple closed records put only one open one?

Based on the logic in the question, I am guessing (2).  If (3), then this probably is not the right approach.

Comment: Actually, neither. Primary key should be (personId,dateX) as it is. There is one record for each person on each day, and until the time is right, it is completely accessible to modification. However, when these records are being processed by a script, they should be kept in the database for the record, but shouldn't be subject to be modification anymore. Of course, I could move them to a different table, but if possible I'd really like to keep them in the same table, changing just the flag "closed", so the same record can't be modified anymore.